# Proof of the proposition (Morse function in $\mathbb{C}$)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, morse-theory, inverse-function-theorem

I was trying to prove the [Proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564934/fu-v-uvu2v-can-be-written-as-u2v2-by-the-change-of-coordinate-in-some) asked by OP. I was thinking to apply some version of inverse function theorem as proved in the Morse Lemma. But I am not able to do it. Can you please give me some hints to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof can be done by using the special case of the [Hadamrad Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) ($n=2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the function $f$ in the proposition is assumed holomorphic. Given that, a proof of the complex morse lemma is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent#Complex_Morse_Lemma

and a google search will lead you to other similar versions.

Comment: Yes, the function is holomorphic.